# How do I modify a keyboard shortcut that doesn't show up in the shortcut list?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, remapping

If you look at [this Apple support page](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1343) there's a big list of shortcuts that are not listed in *System Preferences → Keyboard → Keyboard Shortcuts*.

Specifically, <kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> is interfering with a very useful shortcut of a program I use.

How can I change/remove this shortcut from the OS?

Comment: As these shortcuts interfere, it's likely that the user is using a cross-platform non-Cocoa application whose menu item keyboard shortcuts cannot be changed. I mean, who'd develop an OS X application and not be aware of a global shortcut such as this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any way to remove the shortcut, but you can change it.

1. Open the Keyboard & Mouse Preference Pane.
2. Click on the *Keyboard Shortcuts* tab.
3. Click the *Add* button (looks like a Plus sign).
4. Be sure that the *Application* drop down is set to `All Applications`.
5. In the *Menu Title* box, enter `Hide Others`.
6. Click in the *Keyboard Shortcut* box and press the keyboard shortcut you'd like to change it to.
7. Click *Add* to save changes.

Instructions adapted from a [Macrumors guide](http://guides.macrumors.com/Changing_Keyboard_Shortcuts).